# How to add a line on top and bottom of a text in a table?

Tags: tables, cline

I am trying to add a line to the top and bottom of a column in my table. Is there a specific command for that?

I tried using \cline but it only adds one line to the bottom.

Comment: Use `\cline` before and after? Please provide a minimal working example showing what you've got. Almost certainly, you should use `booktabs` rules rather than `\cline` anyway.

Comment: For `booktabs`, there's `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` (and `\midrule`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example.  Also, use `\hline` for horizontal lines that span the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}cp{1in}cp{1.5in}}
\cline{2-3}
\lipsum[1] & 1 & \lipsum[2] & 2 & \lipsum[3]    \\
\cline{3-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```